# Only Clicking away from flyout should close flyout - if clicked inside or on flyout shouldn't close it

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

I've two Div's on my page. one is parent div(Notification Icon), another div as pop-up(Notification Flyout). Currently Flyout is shown/hide on click of parent div or clicking on button inside Flyout  window.

How can I achieve that Flyout  will be closed(hide) when I click away (anywhere outside Flyout and parent div) ? is there any event mechanism already provided ? if yes, How to use it?

I want to do it angular way and without dialogs.

Code :

```
<md-icon md-font-icon="material-icons" class="md-icon-button">notifications</md-icon>
<div class="notification-flyout" ng-show="activeNotification">
    <div data-ng-include src="'assets/ng-app/pages/notification/notification-template.html'"></div>
<div>
    <div class="notification-button"
         ng-click="openNotifications()">
        View All Notifications
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved the problem with

```
$(window).click(function() {
     //Hide the menus if visible
});

$('.notification-flyout').click(function(event){
    event.stopPropagation();
});
```